# Cross-Fade Image Transition on Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very simple HTML page with one image and one button. The idea is that, when the button is clicked, the image changes to another image.

At the moment I have succeeded in changing the image when clicking the button by using the following javascript:

```
document.getElementById("img").src="img2.jpg";
```

However, I would like to know if there is some easy and simple way to make the change like a transition, for example a cross-fade between both images, with only javascript and css.

Comment: I'm assuming u dont want jquery?

Comment: I am a beginner, and I have never used it, so if it could be performed only with javascript/css it would be very helpful, but if jquery has a very easy way of doing it i might as well learn it too!

Comment: No, there is no simple way for doing it (by simple I mean a CSS one-liner). You could do it by overlapping both the old and the new pictures (having two `img` elements). As soon as you change the `src` the image instantly changes.

Comment: Yes, it changes instantly, this is why I thought it'd be cool to have some sort of transition, but I have been searching for a while and can't find anything that works with only js/css...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in a step-by-step process:

1. Create an img element at the same position of the original image.
2. Increase the z-index of said element
3. Hide the element
4. Add element into the DOM
5. Fade it slowly into the view.

See the **WORKING SNIPPET** BELOW:

**SOLN 1: using pure Javascript & `filter: alpha` without CSS3 for even old browsers like IE-5+:**

```js
function act() {
  var element = document.createElement("img");
  element.src = "http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg";
  var op = 0.1; // initial opacity
  element.style.opacity = op;
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.style.display = 'block';
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op >= 1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")"; // IE 5+ Support
    op += op * 0.1;
  }, 50);
}
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='act()'>FADE CHANGE</button>
<br />
<img id="img" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/287.jpg">
```

**SOLN 2: Alternate soln with CSS3 Transitions for IE10+, Chrome 26+, Fx 16+, Op 12.1+ :**

```js
var element = document.createElement("img");
element.src = "http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg";
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.style.opacity = 0;
element.style.transition = "opacity 1s";

function act() {
  element.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='act()'>FADE CHANGE</button>
<br />
<img id="img" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/287.jpg">
```

*Note: I haven't been able to actually test in really old browsers like IE 6 but theoretically should work well. Comment if you find a discrepancy.*

Comment: This does almost exactly what I wanted, but is there the possibility of performing a cross-fade? I mean, not fade the first and the appear the second, but appear the second on top of the first maybe?

Comment: @MartaSampietro done!! chk the edit, its a cross-over as you expected

Comment: I think it will! I am just trying to adapt it to my page, because I had some styling and now I am trying to make it all look nice. But yes, thanks a lot, it does what I wanted!

Comment: @MartaSampietro Perfect!! glad it helped.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why do you use `setInterval` in JavaScript rather than `transition` in CSS? Is there a performance win?

Comment: @Rounin no, i just wrote that soln initially, probably will write an additional aoln using css later tonight when im free.

Comment: @Rounin that said ie8 below, i think css transitions don't work.

Comment: Ah, okay. Legacy browser compatibility is fair enough. ;-)

Comment: @Rounin It's sad but true. :D When will ppl learn to update. It seems like only yesterday we used to check for `ActiveXObject` ... :( hope this will change soon too.

Comment: If new browsers cost lots of money, then I'd understand. If new browsers took hours to install then I'd understand. But new browsers take 2-3 minutes to install and they are free. I'm sure I'd have no problem explaining to someone with a black and white TV: "No you can't watch TV in colour until you plug in and switch on this free colour TV. If you don't want to do that, that's also fine - but you'll be watching TV in black and white."

Comment: @Rounin NOW 1 soln with css3 for 'normal' users, and another with no css3 for IE 5+ support for the rest of them (using `filter: alpha(opacity=50);` :D had forgotten that even existed.)

Answer (score 1):

Fade in and out the images.
This is the easiest way to do it, but there will be no cross-fade.

CSS:

```
img { 
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
var img = document.getElementById('i');
setInterval(function() { 
  img.className += ' hidden';
  img.src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/";

  setTimeout(function() {
    img.className = img.className.replace('hidden', '');
  }, 100);
}, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9tksj3fa/2/

Comment: Good to see CSS animations are used, to get the best available performance.

Comment: @TimVisée OP mentioned in his comments he doesn't use `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can position one `img` squarely over the top of the other and then give one `img` an `opacity` of `1` and the other `img` an `opacity` of `0`.

Then, when the `button` is clicked, the opaque `img` will `transition` to an `opacity` of `0` and the transparent `img` will transition to an `opacity` of `1`.

**Example:**

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];


function crossFade() {

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].classList.toggle('transparent');
        images[i].classList.toggle('opaque');
    }
}


button.addEventListener('click',crossFade,false);
```

```css
button, .images {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin: 24px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.image-1, .image-2 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
}

.images, .image-1, .image-2 {
width: 140px;
height: 140px;
}

.image-1 {
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.image-2 {
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

.opaque {
opacity: 1;
}

.transparent {
opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Cross Fade</button>

<div class="images">
<img class="image-1 opaque" alt="Image 1" />
<img class="image-2 transparent" alt="Image 2" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want "image B" fade in when "image A" is fading out.

I think you can let "image B" first on top of "image A", but make it `opacity: 0`

Also, you can use `transition-delay` which can let the transition of "image B"

defer a little bit

I guess this is the what you mean "cross-fade"

http://jsbin.com/sigihazuka/edit?html,css,js,output

#### conclusion

1. "image B" on top of "image A", but it will be transparent
2. when user click "image A", we add class "fade-out" on "image A" and "fade-in-delay" on "image B"
3. when "fade-out" complete, add class "hide" on "image A"